# How to fix NullPointerException thrown by FileWriter

Tags: java, file, nullpointerexception, filewriter

I'm getting the following exception when I run my code.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:228)
at java.base/java.io.FileWriter.<init>(FileWriter.java:113)
at FileLogger.log(FileLogger.java:39)
at Mapping.main(Mapping.java:104)
```

Here is the code:

```java
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

public class FileLogger implements Logger {
    private static final String FILE_LOGGER_NAME = "FileOutput.txt";

    static File f;

    static {
        try {
            File f = new File(FILE_LOGGER_NAME);
            if (f.delete()) {
                f.createNewFile();
            } else {
                f.createNewFile();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void log(String message) {
        try {
            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(f, true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // METHOD UNFINISHED
    }
}
```

I'm creating a FileWriter object with `boolean append = true` and the File object `f` declared and populated in the static block above the `log(String message)` method.
What exactly is causing this exception and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The member variable `f` is never initialized.

You use a local variable `f` in the static initializer block.